# How to disable MySQL timestamp default constraints and update triggers?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, timestamp, database-backups

Temporarily disabling foreign key checks helps a lot when what you need is to populate an empty database with data backed up previously without following the original order of the records inserting.

In my case I also need to insert timestamp columns data overriding the ways they are written norally (`added` defined as `timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` and set by a `NEW.added = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` trigger and `updated` defined as `timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) to keep the timestamps unchanged on a backup restore.

So is there a way to just turn all triggers and default constraints off temporarily and on back again shortly after or do I have to dropp every constraint and trigger like that manually and bring them back manually again in such a case?

Comment: I think, dropping constraints temporarily seems only option now